# Selected drop down menu item not being rendered

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, drop-down-menu

Currently I have multiple drop downs that I have created in a JSP. I have created a permalink which is working perfectly that when I select specific item the permalink updates to contain that item. Now when I click the permalink it displays in the URL such as `permalink/selectedItem`. My goal is to be able to copy that permalink into a new tab and have all the selected items appear in the drop down menu that were selected in the previous tab. For example if I had selected dog in the drop down menu and clicked on permalink and copied the permalink which contains `permalink/dog` then my new tab should have a drop down menu that had selected the word dog. It is not showing the word dog though which is my problem. It always goes back to the default select choice even tho the link contains the word dog!. Even when I right click and view source, the page has said `<option selected> Dog</option>` in the list of options that I have. So that's working its just not showing up. Here is my code related to it:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `value` attribute, i.e.: `<option value='Dog' selected> Dog</option>` You're only giving your options the display name.

```
 <option value='<%= typeOfAnimal %>' <%= choice.equals(typeOfAminal) ? "selected" : "" %>>
```

Also, I would reverse the order of `choice.equals(typeOfAminal)` to `typeOfAminal.equals(choice)` because `choice` could be `null` (coming from the request) while `typeOfAminal` can't be (coming from a static list or the db), and if you do it the first way and `choice` is `null` you would get a NullPointerException.